# Canonical technique for POSTing an array of objects with REST

Tags: jquery, rest, grails

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I looked over Stack Overflow and didn't see a similar question, but if I missed one I apologize.

So I'm building a RESTful API, along with a user interface that is the (first) consumer of said REST API.

I have a need to create an object. The creation of that object takes a decent amount of configuration.

I understand about the verb I need to use (POST - let's not argue this point) and the URL path that I need to have. My question is about how to configure the parameters. Let me give you a sample configuration object in JSON format so as to be agnostic:

```
    { 
     name: "foo",
     barid:1, 
     features:[
        {
         id:1, 
         config: {
            foo:bar, 
            fubar:baz
         } 
        }, 
        {
         id:2, 
         config: {
            foo:bar, 
            fubar:baz
         }
        },... 
    ]  
   }
```

So what I'm wondering is this... what's the correct way to POST the features parameter? Should I just make "features" a JSON string and deserialize it on the server side? Is there some convention that you follow to build an array of nested objects in a RESTful POST? Other developers are going to have to consume this, and I certainly don't want people to have to hand-construct what jQuery did with my JSON object, which looked like:

```
features[0][featureid]:2
features[0][configuration][min]:-64
features[0][configuration][max]:50
features[0][include]:true
features[1][featureid]:3
features[1][configuration][min]:0
features[1][configuration][max]:80.5
features[1][include]:true
```

My grails app didn't like that very much :)

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails can accept parameters like `features[0].featured=2&features[0].configuration.min=-64`, but you must prepare empty structures and features array before actual mapping. It would be:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils
import org.apache.commons.collections.Factory

class DataCommand {

  String name

  List features = = ListUtils.lazyList([], {
      new FeatureCommand(
          configuration: new ConfigurationCommand()
      )
  } as Factory)

}
```

+

```
class FeatureCommand {
    int featured
    ConfigurationCommand configuration
}

class ConfigurationCommand {
    int min
    int max
}
```

`lazyList` creates list elements on demand. If you know exactly amount of features - you can fill it manually w/o using lazyList.

Btw, it's also a good way to POST/PUT actual JSON in body to server, instead of request parameters. It's default way of BackboneJS, for example. So you will be able to parse incoming JSON by yourself, of map to same commands (requires little configuration).

Comment: Hey Splix - I didn't know that about Grails and I appreciate the heads up. I will use that in the future (and may refactor another app to use that) but in the end I'm really asking a question about REST, not about Grails. Because others are going to be consuming my RESTful API, I want to operate on the principle of least surprise and make sure that my API is something that they consume in the way they would expect it to work regardless of language and platform.

Comment: You can use standard JSON (as POST body), it's common, and seems that most languages can use JSON. If you prefer query params - I don't see any problem with `features[0].featured=2` format, it's common too (and it's first time when i saw `features[0][featured]:2`)